# How do I create a named has_many and belongs_to association in Rails 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

I have a model named Comics. My overall goal is to allow every comic to have optional variants(has_many comics) and a single variant_of(belongs_to comic). When I add a variant_of, I expect the inverse variants field to also resemble the same relationship.

I started by creating a variant_of migration:

```
class AddVariantOfToComics < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :comics, :variant_of, :integer
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :comics, :variant_of, :integer
  end
end
```

It worked splendidly. Then I attempted to make a variants index, which is the aspect I am having trouble with:

```
class AddVariantsToComics < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :comics, ['variant_of'], :name => 'variants' 
  end
end
```

The comics model:

```
class Comic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :variants, :class_name => "Comic", :foreign_key => 'variants', 
  belongs_to :variant_of, :class_name => "Comic", :foreign_key => 'variant_of'

  ...
end
```

Can anyone tell me how to relate these fields? Is index the right way to do that or is my naming getting in the way?

Comment: I don't really know what it is that you want to accomplish.  Can you explain in words what you want the end result to be able to do?

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key of the `has_many` association is supposed to be `variant_of`. Like:

`has_many :variants, :class_name => "Comic", :foreign_key => 'variant_of'`

And it is not supposed to have a comma after it. In your example it is: `:foreign_key => 'variants',` which is not a valid syntax.